# Controlling calls and sms (Phonegap/Android)

Tags: android, cordova, blacklist

I use phonegap. Is there any call and sms events ? Can I develop a blacklist program using phonegap ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#startcallbutton

Comment: no this event fires when startcall button pressed.

Comment: Sorry friend. I have no knowledge regarding Phonegap. Just tried to help you out.